# Sequelize isn't creating foreign columns (postgres)

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I am trying to learn to use sequelize to create some tables (this isn't production), I know how to do this via basic SQL commands but I am trying to figure out how to use sequelize (in school)

I am trying to create three tables via these commands.

```
node_modules/.bin/sequelize model:create --name movies--attributes "title:string,description:string,image_url:string,year:integer,date_obtained:date,rating:integer,notes:text"
node_modules/.bin/sequelize model:create --name borrowers --attributes "firstname:string,lastname:string,email:string"
node_modules/.bin/sequelize model:create --name types --attributes "name:string"
```

Then I go into movies.js and change the associations

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var movies = sequelize.define('movies', {
    title: DataTypes.STRING,
    description: DataTypes.STRING,
    image_url: DataTypes.STRING,
    year: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    date_obtained: DataTypes.DATE,
    rating: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    notes: DataTypes.TEXT
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        movies.belongsToMany(models.borrowers);
        movies.belongsToMany(models.types);
      }
    }
  });
  return movies;
};
```

As well as borrowers.js

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var borrowers = sequelize.define('borrowers', {
    firstname: DataTypes.STRING,
    lastname: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        borrowers.hasMany(models.movies);
      }
    }
  });
  return borrowers;
};
```

and types.js

```
    'use strict';
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var types = sequelize.define('types', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        types.hasMany(models.movies);
      }
    }
  });
  return types;
};
```

and run

```
node_modules/.bin/sequelize db:migrate
```

But the columns (I would expect something like borrower_id and type_id) are not being created in movies. In another test, I tried to manually create the borrower_id in movies and I got this error when I tried to do an insert

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: column "borrowerId" does not exist
```

So it is trying to reference the column but it isn't being created? Any help would be greatly appreciated, I am learning and obviously missing something.

Comment: I ended up dumping everything and recreating the columns manually. That seemed to fix the problem.